# What can I do to settle this error "raise googlemaps.exceptions.Timeout()" in working with Google places api?

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have to get some details of some places. I wrote a code in Python to automate this using Google places API. I used two queries to automate this function. They are *'nearby search'* and *'place details'*. I could get some place details after executing the program. But, while executing the program, `googlemaps.exceptions.Timeout` exception occured. I'm not enabled billing yet. Is this a problem in my code or some other issue? will this error be solved after enable billing?

```
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key = API_Key)

def search_places(location, radius, type):
    places = gmaps.places_nearby(location = location, radius = radius, type = type)
    time.sleep(3)
    pprint.pprint(places)
    for place in places['results']:
        place_id = place['place_id']
        fields = ['name', 'formatted_address', 'formatted_phone_number', 'rating', 'website']
        place_details = gmaps.place(place_id = place_id, fields = fields)
        pprint.pprint(place_details)
        time.sleep(3)

search_places('40.712776,-74.005974', '20000', 'restaurant')
```

Error is:

```
raise googlemaps.exceptions.Timeout()
```

Answer (score 1):

You **do** need to enable billing for the Places API to work. Check out [Google's Billing documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage-and-billing).

> Reminder: To use the Places API, you must include an API key with all
>   API requests and you **must enable billing on each of your projects**.

Hope this helps.